# EXCEL - Bloquear rango en una funcion

Tags: excel

Al aplicar una fucnion en excel:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2 =VLOOKUP(A2; '2018'!C1:C200; 1 ;FALSE); TRUE; FALSE); FALSE)
```

cuando aplico lo mimos a todas una columna (arrastrando la propriedad), me modifica uno de los paramentros de busqueda C1:C200 -> C2:C201 -> C3:C202 ... 
Como se puede mantener fijo el rango de busqueda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente debes añadir un signo de $ en la fila o columna que deseas fijar, por ejemplo en tu caso seria asi:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2 =VLOOKUP(A2; '2018'!$C$1:$C$200; 1 ;FALSE); TRUE; FALSE); FALSE)
```

Una forma rápida para fijar rangos es presionar `F4` al momento de seleccionar el rango, también puedes hacer un mix, por ejemplo si pones `$C1:$C200` solo fijas la columna, las filas si se modificaran, si pones `C$1:C$200` solo fijaras las filas. Espero que te funcione.

Answer (score 0):

Para bloquear un rango de celdas, tienes que utilizar referencias absolutas:

[Cambiar entre referencias relativas, absolutas y mixtas/mixtas con autorización](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/cambiar-entre-referencias-relativas-absolutas-y-mixtas-mixtas-con-autorizaci%C3%B3n-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9).

En tu caso, si quieres bloquear el rango `C1:C200` deberías poner `$C$1:$C$200`